# Reddit GET returns 403 even though the token is correct

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, httpwebrequest, reddit

I'm trying to interface with Reddit API, but running into some issues on the GET after retrieving my access_token. I have confirmed the token and required scopes to complete this operation:

```
        Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, "TOKEN : " + myItem.myAccessKey.accessKeyString, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/me");
        myRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        myRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + myItem.myAccessKey.accessKeyString);
        var myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse(); //403 forbidden here
        if (myResponse == null)
        {
            Finish();
        }
        var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        myResponse.Close();
        myStreamReader.Close();
```

Comment: 403 means forbidden - you aren't *authorized* to use a URL even though authentication succeded. Are you sure this is the correct URL?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/

I hadn't considered I'd be using the wrong URL. I'll try to figure out if I'm using the wrong URL, thanks!

Comment: The URL you tried is `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/me`

Comment: response = requests.get("https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me", headers=headers)

Comment: https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me Yeah I'm using the wrong URL. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 means Forbidden. Authentication succeeded, ie the token and headers are correct, but you don't have permission to GET the URL you typed, `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/me`